# How to reload the collection view data in table view cell after clicking another table view cell's collection view data in swift 3?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview

Here I am loading collection view data dynamically in table view cell and table view cells also created on dynamic json array count and here after selecting any element in collection view which is in first table view cell then the collection view needs to be reloaded with new data which is in second table view cell can anyone help me how to reload the collection view in second table view cell swift 3 if this is not possible can anyone provide me any alternative layout to implement this ?

Here is my cell for row method

```
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
           let cell = addToCartTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addToCartCollectionCell") as! AddToCartCollectionTableViewCell
            cell.configurableProduct = self.detailModel
            print(self.detailModel)
            cell.collectionView.tag = indexPath.row
            self.addToCartTableView.setNeedsLayout()
            self.addToCartTableView.layoutIfNeeded()
            cell.collectionView.reloadData()
            cell.cellLabel.text = detailModel?.extensionAttribute?.productOptions[indexPath.row].label
            if detailModel?.extensionAttribute?.productOptions[indexPath.row].label == "Size"{
                cell.sizeGuideBtn.isHidden = false
            }else{
                cell.sizeGuideBtn.isHidden = true
            }
            cell.getCurrentRow = indexPath.row
            return cell
        }else {
            let cell = addToCartTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addToCartQtyCell") as! AddToCartQuantityTableViewCell
            self.addToCartTableView.setNeedsLayout()
            self.addToCartTableView.layoutIfNeeded()
            cell.QtyLabel.text = "Qty"
            return cell
        }
```

Here is my table view cell code

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        print(getCurrentRow)
        // Initialization code
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
       return CGSize(width: 50, height: 30)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(configurableProduct?.extensionAttribute?.productOptions[getCurrentRow].values.count)
        return (configurableProduct?.extensionAttribute?.productOptions[getCurrentRow].values.count)!
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! AddToCartCollectionViewCell
    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        let items = configurableProduct?.extensionAttribute?.productOptions[getCurrentRow].values[indexPath.row]
        cell.collectionLabel.text =  "\(items?.valueIndex as! Int)"
        if indexPath.item == self.selectedIndex{
            cell.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.007509540026, green: 0.6581087804, blue: 0.01165772038, alpha: 1)
        }else if self.selectedIndex == nil {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }else{
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }
    }
    else {
        if selectedValue != nil {
            for item in (self.configurableProduct?.extensionAttribute?.productStock)! {
                //                            let jsonStr = "{\"label\":\"57-175\",\"stock\":0}"
                let dict = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: item.data(using: .utf8)!, options: []) as! [String:Any]
                let labelValue = dict["label"] as! String
                print(labelValue)
                let values:[String] = labelValue.components(separatedBy: "-")
                print(values)
                self.colorNumber = Int(values[0])
                self.sizeNumber = Int(values[1])
                let stock = dict["stock"] as! Int
                let value = selectedValue
                if value == self.colorNumber {
                    if stock != 0 {
                        self.sizeArray.append(self.sizeNumber!)
                        print(self.sizeArray)
                        cell.collectionLabel.text =  "\(self.sizeNumber)"
                    }
                }
            }
            if indexPath.item == self.selectedIndex{
                cell.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.007509540026, green: 0.6581087804, blue: 0.01165772038, alpha: 1)
            }else if self.selectedIndex == nil {
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            }else{
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            }
        }
        else {
            let items = configurableProduct?.extensionAttribute?.productOptions[getCurrentRow].values[indexPath.item]
            print(items?.valueIndex)
            for item in (self.configurableProduct?.extensionAttribute?.productStock)! {
                //                            let jsonStr = "{\"label\":\"57-175\",\"stock\":0}"
                let dict = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: item.data(using: .utf8)!, options: []) as! [String:Any]
                let labelValue = dict["label"] as! String
                print(labelValue)
                let values:[String] = labelValue.components(separatedBy: "-")
                print(values)
                self.colorNumber = Int(values[0])
                self.sizeNumber = Int(values[1])
                let stock = dict["stock"] as! Int
                let value = self.selectedIndex
                if value == self.colorNumber {
                    if stock != 0 {
                        self.sizeArray.append(self.sizeNumber!)
                        print(self.sizeArray)
                        cell.collectionLabel.text =  "\(items?.valueIndex as! Int)"
                    }
                }else {
                    cell.collectionLabel.text =  "\(items?.valueIndex as! Int)"
                }
            }
            if indexPath.item == self.selectedIndex{
                cell.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.007509540026, green: 0.6581087804, blue: 0.01165772038, alpha: 1)
            }else if self.selectedIndex == nil {
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            }else{
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            }
        }
    }
    return cell
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if collectionView.tag == 0 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! AddToCartCollectionViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.007509540026, green: 0.6581087804, blue: 0.01165772038, alpha: 1)
        cell.collectionLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        cell.collectionLabel.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.007509540026, green: 0.6581087804, blue: 0.01165772038, alpha: 1)
        self.dataSelected = true
        self.selectedIndex = indexPath.item
        print(self.selectedIndex)
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        self.sizeArray.removeAll()
        self.selectedValue = configurableProduct?.extensionAttribute?.productOptions[1].values[indexPath.item].valueIndex
        self.getCurrentRow = 1
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    print(self.selectedValue)
    }
    else {
        print(collectionView.tag)
    }
}
```

here is my layout image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

in didSelectItemAt of collection view, reload the table cell which contains size by doing

```
let indexpath = IndexPath(item: value, section: 0)
tableview.reloadRows(at: [indexpath], with: .none)
```

here **value** is position of row which you want to upate

Answer (score 0):

Create a new variable "cellObj" which data type is same as you custom cell where you added collection view.

```
var cellObj:AddToCartCollectionTableViewCell!
```

After add assign cellObj value after this line.

```
let cell = addToCartTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addToCartCollectionCell") as! AddToCartCollectionTableViewCell
cellObj = cell
```

*** After doing you are able to reload collection view any where.

```
cellObj.collectionView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

DispatchQueue.main.async {

```
           // cell!.tableView.reloadData()
            collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
            cell!.tableView.reloadData()
        }
           })
```